# MySQL Join Best Practice on Large Data

Tags: mysql, join, sharding

table1_shard1 (1,000,000 rows per shard x 120 shards)

```
 id_user   hash
```

table2 (100,000 rows)

```
 value    hash
```

Desired Output:

```
 id_user  hash    value
```

I am trying to find the fastest way to associate **id_user** with **value** from the tables above.

My current query ran for 30 hours without result.

```
SELECT 
    table1_shard1.id_user, table1_shard1.hash, table2.value 
FROM table1_shard1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1_shard1.hash=table2.hash 
GROUP BY id_user
UNION
SELECT 
    table1_shard2.id_user, table1_shard2.hash, table2.value 
FROM table1_shard1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1_shard2.hash=table2.hash 
GROUP BY id_user
UNION 
( ... )
UNION 
SELECT 
    table1_shard120.id_user, table1_shard120.hash, table2.value 
FROM table1_shard1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1_shard120.hash=table2.hash 
GROUP BY id_user
```

Comment: How about loading table2 into a memory table? That should speed things up a bit. Are there indexes created on the tablesfields that are part of the link (table1.hash and table2.hash) ?

Comment: Can't you merge the shards in one table ? I thing the union is too heavy

Comment: Indexes on id_user, hash, and value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, do you have indexes on the `hash` fields

I think you should merge your tables in one before the query (at least temporarily)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_shards
SELECT * FROM table1_shard1;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_shards
SELECT * FROM table1_shard2;

# ...
```

Then do the main query

```
SELECT
  table1_shard120.id_user
, table1_shard120.hash
, table2.value
FROM tmp_shards AS shd
LEFT JOIN table2 AS tb2 ON (shd.hash = tb2.hash)
GROUP BY id_user
;
```

Not sure for the performance gain but it'll be at least more maintainable.

Comment: Problem is the 120 x 1,000,000 data is about 250GB.

Comment: Seems weird that it takes soo much memory for a table with only 3 fields. What are the field types ? Do you have indexes on `hash`

Comment: There is a lot more data other than these 3 fields.. I just excluded it for the simplicity of this post.

Comment: Indexes are on id_user, hash, and value. Field types are int, varchar, varchar (respectively).

Comment: Ok this is good. Did you try to make unit tests with one table. For example trying to remove half of the fields to see if it's faster.

Comment: I have tried and on a single shard the data still does not even load within 2 hours. It's very, very slow.

Comment: Copy a shard and keep only 1000 records then test on that. Can you paste a DESCRIBE of a shard in your question ?